# Is it possible to require certain Vagrant and VirtualBox versions in Vagrantfile?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I recently noticed that I managed to have a version of Vagrant and VirtualBox installed that did not work with my `Vagrantfile`. Upgrading to the latest Vagrant & VirtualBox fixed the problem.

Is it possible to ensure minimum Vagrant and VirtualBox versions are installed before allowing `vagrant up` to launch?

Comment: For vagrant there's Vagrant.require_version: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/vagrant_version.html

Comment: Thanks @Emyl. If you mind to create an answer about this same, I am happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Vagrant itself, there is [built-in support](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/vagrant_version.html):

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.3.5"
```

For Virtualbox, you can run some code at the top of your Vagrantfile like this:

```
if Gem::Version.new(`VBoxManage --version`.strip) < 
Gem::Version.new('5.1.6')
  abort "Please upgrade Virtualbox to 5.1.6 or later!"
end
```